Volatile or not? Multithreaded algorithm with special constraints
I am about to implement an algorithm giving me special constraints a can rely on and I wonder if my consideration about correctness of the output is correct. So here the details:
About the algorithm:

The data structure is just one big std::vector<uint8_t> data; (big in the sense that the entire vector will need 4GiB memory or more, or size() is about 2^32 or higher).
The algorithm is performed in multiple steps.
Right before running step n (n= 1, 2, ...), n can be 254 at max, we know that at each vector position the value is either strict less than n or it is MAX = 255.
At step n the algorithm only reads at positions i where data[i] < n.
At step n the algorithm updates some of the positions i where data[i] == 255 by assigning data[i] = n;
The algorithm makes a lot of calculation and might also try to update a position i multiple times. But it only updates if the value was 255. All calculation whether position i has to be updated only relies on the positions j where data[j] < n.

Note that after finishing step n, we end up just before step n+1 and the same conditions hold for n+1.
Here my considerations about multithreading and correctness:
(If I do all operations sequentially then of course everything works fine.) Let's assume we run the algorithm in parallel with up to (m= 4, 8, 16, 32, ...) threads.

Note that all values are single bytes, so we know that reading / writing operations on RAM are atomic by architecture on that low level. (We will never have two concurrent writers writing a multi-byte data structure where we end up in mixed data from both writers. A reader always reads an updated value or an outdated old value but never mixed bits of old and new value.) Of course, we still might end up with one thread reading an outdated value which has just been updated by another thread.
Note that two threads might update a position i concurrently. But that does not matter. They are both updating data[i] = n; We don't care which thread writes back to memory last and overwrites the other(s). They all write the same.
I might use volatile for the data (std::vector<volatile uint8_t> data;) to force the compiler to write back every single update directly to RAM, i.e. to not allow caching writes in particular. But I don't have to do so. Let them all cache their write-backs, I do not care. I join() all threads at the end of step n. They will all write back to RAM at this time if they have not done before. As argued before, I do not care who writes last.

Can you check my arguments and declare what is wrong and explain why in case you find mistakes?
Would you recommend using volatile here or not and why?

Relevant reading (regarding volatile): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading You may also want to actually try it out in code and see if any inconsistencies emerge or if it triggers any sanitizers.

Question too broad, and the answers would be "it depends". In principle, whenever more than 1 thread writes to the same memory, it's a data race and must be protected by atomics or some sync mechanism (mutex). Having data[i] being updated to the same value from multiple threads should work on modern CPUs, but is questionable from design point of view.

In short, any sort of scenario where multiple threads access the same uint8_t object requires synchronization, and this means mutexes, atomics, etc. volatile providesno synchronization and what you're trying to do sounds like UB. It's also a myth that you can treat small fundamental types as quasi-atomic just because it would be okay in x86 assembly. It's still a data race in C++, it might be optimized incorrectly, and it still triggers thread sanitizers. Use atomics, tossvolatile`.

@pptaszni it wouldn't work in modern CPUs in general; that's just an x86 thing because all memory operations on x86 effectively have acquire/release memory order, and no tearing is gauranteed for small aligned operations. Not every modern architecture gives you the same guarantees. Even if you happen to be on x86, the code will be optimized with the assumption that no multi-threaded access happens to any non-atomic object. Maybe volatile makes it less likely for something to blow up in your face, but I'm sure it's possible to construct some example.
